# why does mediaquery.of() error keep showing up?

Tags: flutter

[image: Click here to see the image]

I am just trying to create an simple widget but it keeps showing this error what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your root widget is not `MaterialApp`, other widgets that you are using need to be descendants of some media query ancestor. Eg. `MaterialApp`.

Instead of this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SomeWidget(),
    );
  }
```

Make it:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SomeWidget(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because your application doesn't return a Material App. Check this code below, it works perfectly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          title: Text('unit converter', textScaleFactor: 1.0,),
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.purpleAccent,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output of the code: 
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because on the top of the tree a `material` widget should be used.

here you can use `Scaffold` or `MaterialApp` widget.

and If you are trying to paint your screen background to some color then just use the parameter `backgroundColor` under your `Scaffold` widget.

Try code shown below

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
    appBar: AppBar(
       backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
       title: Text("unit converter",textScaleFactor:4.0)
    ),
    body: yourWidget()
  );
}
```